# Having trouble building website for a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql, github

I'm trying to build a product launch site with login and signup with a confirmation email sent out. I have made as much as I can figure out but the signup isn't working. I'm very new to this and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

https://github.com/Atoland00/WhiskerWindows.git
This is all the code I have so far. I know very little so I do not know what I have or have not tried really.

Comment: Personally, I would use PHP for user authentication (Or at least a back-end language), not JavaScript. Also, please ask a specific question as to what you are stuck on, and provide information as to what you have tried, what you are trying to do, etc.

Comment: you show learn more about nowaday website concept. What is backend and what is front-end, how does things work. There are many free youtube video teach you that. Learn to use ExpressJS first then try to connect it with your front-end ( using json ) is a good practice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.